# IntelliJ warns NullPointerException

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a method that can return a String and can be a null value, using this code:

```java
private static boolean hasSignificantValue(String identificator) {
    String content = variables.get(identificator); //method
    System.out.println(content == null);
    return (variables.exists(identificator) && content.length() > 0 && !content.equals("null"));
}
```

However, commenting on the exit, I no longer receive this warning

```java
private static boolean hasSignificantValue(String identificator) {
    String content = variables.get(identificator);
    return (variables.exists(identificator) && content.length() > 0 && !content.equals("null"));
}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: What data type is `variables`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which method is returning string? data type of  "variables" ? Which code you are commenting?

Comment: Since content variable can be null. content.equals() and content.length() will throw nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println(content == null);` this line **indicates** that `content` could possibly become a `null`, so which would possibly cause a `NullPointerException` in `content.length()`. So the IDE warns about a potential `NullPointerException`.

So once you remove the null check, then the IDE doesn't see a scenario where `content` would be null (Even though it could **still** be `null` but there is no explicit null check). Hence the warning will not be shown in this case.

So you could do:

```java
String content = variables.get(identificator); //method
if(content == null) {
    System.out.println("Content is null");
    return false;
}

// Execution would reach here only if content is not null. Hence no warning is displayed.
return (variables.exists(identificator) && content.length() > 0 && !content.equals("null"));
```